# Create CString with "" characters

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to create a string for the user which contains "". 
The way how I do this is below :

```
CString fileLink;
fileLink.Format(_T(" some text %s "" text with needed characters "" another %s text "), somevariable1 , somevariable2);
```

But as a result I got string without "".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you escape that character with ´\"´?

Comment: Ok, I will try this.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry... The stackoverflow app did some strange shit there. I hope you can read it now. I just asked if you can't escape your quotation marks:  \"

Comment: Just change your string literal to `" some text %s \" text with needed characters \" another %s text "`

Comment: Yes it works . Thank you.

Comment: Question title and question text are asking for different symbols. The symbols in the title can be placed into any string as is. The symbols in the question body need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @Exhauzt is works.
Need to use \" in your string.

```
" some text %s \" text with needed characters \" another %s text "
```

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape for detailed description